# How to load vitamio on my emulator for streaming m3u8

Tags: android, m3u8

I hawe written an app for streaming from a url that a radio station. But when i run on emulator it asked me whether i want to load vitamio from google play or viamio website. vitamio web site is not avaliable and i cant go to google play on my emulator.What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully used the new version of vitamio without downloading external libraries from the google play. The new version has builtin libraries so that you wont have to download external app from google play.that is version 4.0